# url rewriting in mvc4 with razor engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting, query-string, url-rewrite-module

I want to rewrite following url -

`http://localhost:99/Product/CategoryLevel?CategoryId=65&ProductName=Vitamins`

with

`http://localhost:99/Product/Vitamins`,

(or)

`http://localhost:99/Product/CategoryLevel/Vitamins`

(or)

`http://localhost:99/Vitamins`

(or) how to remove (or) hide  the querystring from the url (that was shown to the users)?

I tried using url rewrite module(iis) and asp.net routing and search for the solution in the internet,but i didn't find right solution for this,please suggest any solutions.

Comment: route config is 'routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
           name: "[clv]",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "CategoryLevel", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );'

Answer (score 8):

You must map this route **before** all the other route mappings (routes are evaluated in order):

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Product", // any name meaningful for you is right
  url: "Product/{productName}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "CategoryLevel" }
);
```

This route will catch all the URLS that look like this:

```
http://myserver/Product/X
```

whatever X is. If you do so, your action should look like this:

```
public ActionResult CategoryLevel(string productName)
```

*NOTE: The parameter name must match the segment in the route mapping: `productName`*

So, whenever the user types:

```
http://myserver/Product/Vitamins
```

the action `CategoryLevel` will be executed, and it will receive the `productName` parameter with the value `"Vitamins"`

The problem is that if you have an action `List` which you expect to be invoked like this

```
http://myserver/Product/List
```

the route will map it and will invoke the `CategoryLevel` action with the `productName` = `"List"`

To avoid this you can use this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Product", // any name meaningful for you is right
  url: "ViewProduct/{productName}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "CategoryLevel" }
);
```

Which will be different from the others, and anything will work fine. The URLs specific for this method will look like this:

```
http://myserver/ViewProduct/TheProductName
```

and the other routes will work as expected.

By the way: you should have an specific action for the product, for example `View`, instead of `CategoryLevel`. So, the route and the action would look like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ViewProduct", // any name meaningful for you is right
        url: "ViewProduct/{productName}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "View" }
    );
```

The action, inside the product controller:

```
public ActionResult View(string productName)
```

The route is used both for mapping a user typed url to the corresponding action, and for generating URLs by using some of the MVC helpers, like `Html.ActionLink` or `Url.Action`. So, if you do something like this:

```
Url.Action('View', 'Product', new {productName = "Vitamins"} )
```

you'll get the expected, short URL:

```
http://myserver/ViewProduct/Vitamins
```

I.e. the route map it's a two-way map that can map URLs to actions and viceversa.

Comment: its working but still iam getting like this http://localhost:99/Product/Vitamins?CategoryId=65  but i dont want to display ?CategoryId=65 and i am not able to access the next level@JotaBe

Comment: How are you getting that wrong URL? if you don't need that parameter, don't use it, and it will stop appearing in the url.

Comment: @JotaBe this is nice. But what I don't like about it is, first with this approach if some one calls the original call '/Product/CategoryLevel?CategoryId=65&ProductName=Vitamins' it will not work. Also in case you have some other actions on that controller other than 'List' which you have suggested, you will end up writing a route for each one.

Comment: urls in my mvc4 mobile application:first level:http://localhost:99/Product/CategoryLevel?CategoryId=11&productName=Healthy%20Living,                                  second level:http://localhost:99/Product/CategoryLevel?CategoryId=65&ParentCategoryId=11&ProductName=Vitamins,             third level:http://localhost:99/Product/CategoryLevel?CategoryId=72&ParentCategoryId=65&ProductName=Vitamin%20A@JotaBe

Comment: routeconfig is  routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Product", // any name meaningful for you is right
       url: "Product/{productName}/",
       defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "CategoryLevel" }
   );

           
            routes.MapRoute(
                       name: "Home",
                       url: "{controller}/{action}",
                       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                   );
@JotaBe

Comment: when iam using above code,first level displayed ashttp://localhost:99/Product/Healthy%20Living?CategoryId=11&ParentCategoryId=0 and second level is displayed as http://localhost:99/Product/Vitamins?CategoryId=65&ParentCategoryId=11,but iam not able access the third level@JotaBe

Comment: actionis:public ActionResultCategoryLevel(stringproductName{stringProductName=Request.QueryString["ProductName"];ViewBag.ProductName=ProductName;intCategory=Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CategoryId"]);
            ViewBag.ParentCategoryId = Category;
            int ParentCategoryId = 0;
            if (Request.QueryString["ParentCategoryId"] != null)
{ParentCategoryId=Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ParentCategoryId"]); }Product productInstance =newProduct();IList<CategoryInfo> categories = new List<CategoryInfo>();categories=productInstance.GetCategories(Category,true); @JotaBe

Comment: if i don't use the parameter it will not redirect to the next page, <li><a href="@Url.Action("CategoryLevel", "Product", new { CategoryId = @item._categoryId, ParentCategoryId=@item._parentId, ProductName = @Html.Raw(item._categoryName) })">@Html.Raw(item._categoryName)</a></li>@JotaBe

Comment: Please, edit your question... It's very difficult to view the code inside the comments :( There are solutions for all your old urls to start working again, but I need to see clearly the code that you've added to the comments. Improve your question and it'll be my pleasure to give you further help.

Comment: Please, also explain why are you worried about people using the old url format.

Answer (score -1):

you can use url rewriting middleware ,i used this one to solve mine problem 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: this question is specifically for MVC4 which is not core... its ok if you want to recommend latest approaches but in real work life sometimes we have legacy apps we need to maintain.

Answer (score -2):

You need to edit your `AppData > RouteConfig.cs`

add the next lines of code there (below Default)

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "[Choose a name]",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "CategoryLevel", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And your Controller action should be the following

```
public ActionResult CategoryLevel(string ID)
{
}
```

Comment: i used this code but the url is still same                                                  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
           name: "[clv]",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "CategoryLevel", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );@Devcon 2

Comment: Did you also changed the action in your Controller?

Comment: yes,        public ActionResult CategoryLevel(string ID)                            {-----------------}@Devcon 2